# Finite quotients of ring of integers of local field

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, galois-extensions, local-field, finite-rings

Let $K$ be a non-Archimedean local field, so either a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote its ring of integers and $\pi$ a uniformizer.

Is there a simple description of the finite ring $\mathcal{O}/ \pi^k \mathcal{O}$, for example in terms of the degree of the finite extension?

The case of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ giving $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ is what I would call very simple, and the case of $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$ giving $\mathbb{F}_q[t] / t^n$ is what I would call simple. But I have no intuition about how the case of finite extensions of these two fields could look like.

Comment: This is related, at the very least: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363172/intrinsic-characterisation-of-a-class-of-rings/363193#363193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F=Q_p$ or $F_p((t))$, $$O_K/(\pi_K^k) = \{ \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \pi_K^m s_m, s_m \in S\}$$ where $S$ are representatives of the residue field, from which the $O_F/(\pi_F^{\lceil  k/e \rceil})$-module structure follows easily (free module if $e | k$, non-free otherwise).

The ring structure is less obvious, it depends on the minimal polynomial of $\pi_K$.
$$O_K = O_F[\zeta_{q-1}][\pi_K]=O_F[x]/\psi(x)[y]/(f(x,y))$$ For [$k$ large enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group) then $$O_K/(\pi_K^k)=O_F/(\pi_F^{\lceil  k/e \rceil})[x]/\psi(x)[y]/(f(x,y))$$

When $p\nmid e$ (tamely ramified) then $f(x,y) = y^e-\pi_F y^r$ for some $r$.

(If $e\nmid k$ then quotient by $y^k$)

Comment: So taking the first description, can I just add and multiply using distributivity and the addition and multiplication in the residue field?